# CoffeeScript code coverage

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, code-coverage, istanbul

Is it possible to execute code coverage on CofeeScript sources without using CoffeeScriptRedux compiler (this one is use in ibrik). I understand advantages of this new compiler but looks like it's still not completed and doesn't work for my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be nice to know more about your application but for most cases the response is yes.

For a Node application and using Mocha for unit tests, I used this project: https://github.com/benbria/coffee-coverage that will compile your Coffee files to add coverage instructions.

And then you can use applications such as: https://github.com/cainus/node-coveralls that will digest the previous reports and make it human readable.

But I know that the main Javascript Coverage frameworks can be compatible with Coffeescript.

For example, Blanket seems to be: https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/blob/master/docs/compatibility_and_features.md#coffeescript-in-the-browser

The advantage of Blanket is that you can use it for a Node application as well as in the Browser (With Jasmine, or whatever). Also Blanket, compared to the other project, doesn't force you to change your test "require" statements.

Comment: As far as you are the only one who responded you win:) But I still didn't find a good way to run code coverage on my project (https://github.com/volkhin/RoadTrafficSimulator). Anyway, thanks for help. Maybe I will just compile CoffeeScript into JS and run code coverage on JS. Should be good enough for the beginning.

Comment: Hello. That's nice to you but I feel a bit like a fraud there :) I can only guess you would have preferred a coverage report containing your true Coffee sources? It's true that Blanket render the Javascript compiled file. (And sometimes the percentage is just not enough ^^)

Comment: However, Blanket deal with all that crap automatically. It was very easy to plugged into mocha. It wouldn't be a problem at all to put the configuration in Gulp.

Comment: Sorry for the flood but I provided you with a PR on your project: https://github.com/volkhin/RoadTrafficSimulator/pull/5 Just to show Blanket ability. I'm very curious about your expectation and what can be done better :) (I am NOT a maintainer of Blanket :p)

Comment: It really works thanks a lot! I don't remember exactly what was the problem in the past with blanket, maybe I have tried to use it in different configuration (few week ago I was using jasmine for tests), but I didn't manage to run ibrik due to problems with CoffeeScriptRedux compiler and I decided it's a common problem. Thanks again, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: And yes, I was looking for a solution to show code coverage on coffeescript files, but as I said it's a good start to have it for JS, anyway I'm curious about coverage of methods/branches, not specific lines.